# Doubt in an example from book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In the second edition of the book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee, page 5,

EXAMPLE 1.4 (Spheres) : For each integer $n\geqslant 0$, the unite n-sphere 
$\mathbb{S}^{n}$ is Hausdorff and second-countable because it is a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  To show that it is locally Euclidean, for each index $i = 1, \ldots n+1 $ let $U_{i}^{+}$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ where the ith coordinate is positive:

$U_{i}^{+} = \lbrace{(x_{1}, \ldots , x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} :
 x^{i} > 0 }\rbrace$

Let $f : \mathbb{B}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the continuos functions 
$f(u) = \sqrt{1 - \vert{u}\vert}$

Why  $\,\,$ $U_{i}^{+}\cap\mathbb{S}^{n}$ is the graph of the function

$x^{i} = f(x^{1},\ldots,\hat{x^{i}}, \ldots,x^{n+1})$ ?

where the hat indicates that $x^{i}$ is omitted.

Comment: I suggest you give more context or at least post a part of the text. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to discuss subtleties. (I mean... I've actually read it, and what you say does not sound new to me. But I don't have the reference hear, and many others won't either.)

Comment: I already wrote, part of the paragraph of the book, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: It's like saying the upper half of the unit circle is $y=\sqrt {1-x^2}, x\in (-1,1).$

Comment: Ooooohhhh, now I understand, thank you very much :)